# NextJs application 100% CPU usage

Tags: node.js, next.js

CPU usage spikes easily on all 8 nodes behind pm2. It performs well upon a fresh boot, but it seems to be degraded significantly over time. The memory footprint is fine, usually around 300MB highest.

Comment: if it performs well in first boot, then you must check for any CPU intensive operation

Comment: @Lint any hit to check?

Comment: use a step by step debugger, and have an eye on memory usage too,
if you've a small snippet of code that you think is causing the hike, please post it here

Comment: Have you used node profiler? There might be some helpful info in the output file

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek i have the logs and after uploading it to chrome trace i have little info.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. traffic spiked, spin up 8 core instance, ran nextjs using pm2 in cluster mode. current nextjs v11. It's shooting in the dark but hoping  that upgrading to nextjs v12 solves this issue. Did you manage to figure out the issue @IshMan